# How can I know if a Surface Pro 3 supports a 4k monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a Surface Pro 3 where a user wants to purchase a 4K monitor and use it off of the display port on the device.

I just can't figure out if the display port will support a 4K resoultion.

Comment: How do you know.  You know because the iGPU inside the SP3 supports it.

Comment: What has your research revealed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can. See the [Connect Surface to a TV, monitor, or projector](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/music-photos-and-video/connect-surface-to-a-tv-display-or-projector?os=windows-10#Setup) page at Microsoft. There is a table with maximum resolutions that different Surface models can support in different configurations. Note that 4K monitors are typically 3840 x 2160 pixels.

[image]

Comment: So looking at your link you could have answered yes. And without the link contents your answer is useless.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.